# React Bootstrap column not showing horizontally

Tags: reactjs, grid, react-bootstrap

I'm building a react app and I am having problems getting my react-bootstrap columns to show horizontally. I would like the image to appear next to the text not above it. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
function About() {
  return (
    <Container fluid  className="about-us">
      <Row>
        <Col sm={4}>
            <Image src={require('../techOn.png')} style={{height:"250px", width: "300"}} />
        </Col>
        <Col sm={4}>
            <h2>Meet The Team</h2>
            <p>
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </p>
            <p>
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
                deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think it works, what is the style inside about-us class??

Comment: @asmaa turnd out I needed to add display: flex in the css for the row

Comment: Good to hear that it works, but its wired because `Container` in `react-bootstrap` build on `flexbox`, I think I have to read again in this topic :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add display: flex in css for row

```
  return (
    <Container fluid  className="about-us">
      <Row style={{display:"flex"}}>
        <Col sm={4}>
            <Image src={require('../techOn.png')} style={{height:"250px", width: "300"}} />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4}>
            <h2>Meet The Team</h2>
            <p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
            deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </p>
            <p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
            Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
            deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
```